# How to debugging in chrome on iPad?

Tags: ipad, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, node-webkit

I have been trying to debugging chrome on ipad
and I tried these solutions but didn't worked out.

1. Nodejs Weinre

Answer (score 0):

This link might help you. Afaik you need to do it remote.
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging

Comment: No, Its not iPad. Its android.